# The ESP Game / Google Image Labeler

Tags: google-image-search

What would be the best/easiest way to make something like the ESP Game / Google Image Labeler?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Games With A Purpose (GWAP) takes a lot of time and effort. I implemented a web-based GWAP before using plain HTML and Javascript for the front end (I made extensive use of JQuery libraries). You can use any backend technology you want to handle the synchronization between players, scoring and gathering the data. I used Google App Engine (w/python)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this software.  It looks like it would cover the basics of labeling an image.

http://beta.fromthepage.com/